# TableView scroll indicator overlaps header

Tags: ios, ios5, uiscrollview, uitableview

[image: iphone app table header]

**Situation**

The `TableView` does everything I need it to because it

1. Allows me to animate rows into it (not easily accomplished with a `UIView`)
2. Allows for a non-scrolling header up top.

**Problems**

1. The scroll indicator (top right) is covering the header. I expected it to stop at the bottom of the header but that's not the case apparently.
2. If I allow bouncing and you pull down too far, the header pulls down with the content. That's not okay.

**Realization**

I can fix my current problems by switching to a UIView, but then other problems are introduced.

1. If I animate rows in with a UIView, I have to keep track of all views positions and make sure they all move by the correct distance when a new view is introduced.
2. 1 isn't so bad, but factor in the matter of screen rotation and it becomes a nice place for bugs to make a home.

**Question**

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the scroll indicator you can use:

```
 tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(yourHeaderHeight, 0, 0, 0);
```

If you don't want the header to move when the table view bouncing is enabled you should replace the header with a UIView and the table view should start at the bottom of the UIView

Comment: I may not have to end up going this route, but it's good info none-the-less. +1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something like this

```
containerView
    |
    |--- headerView (subview of containerView)
    | 
    |--- tableView/scrollView (subview of containerView)
```

so you separate the `headerView` from the `tableview` and the scrollView indicator will just be on the tableView.
This is assuming you mean a table view header and not a section header.

Comment: In this idea, is *containerView* still a `UITableViewController` ? Or something else?

Comment: A `UITableviewController` is a subclass of a `UIViewController` so I would add the `containerView` as the `view` property and the `tableView` as the `tableView` property. This should be doable. But haven't tested it myself.